# requireJS optimizer does not include nested require calls

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm reading through the optimizer documentation for quite a while, but it seems like I can't figure it. The doc says:

> The optimizer will only combine modules that are specified in arrays
>   of string literals that are passed to top-level require and define
>   calls, or the require('name') string literal calls in a simplified
>   CommonJS wrapping. So, it will not find modules that are loaded via a
>   variable name:

OK so far so good. This basically means *r.js* won't include nor crawl nested dependencies. Now lets assume we have a "main application" file which looks like the following:

```
require([ 'es5shim', 'tools' ], function() {
    console.log('fictive app entry point');

    require([ 'domready!' ], function( doc ) {
        console.log('domReady, loading GUI modules...');
        require([ 'GUI/window', 'GUI/header', 'GUI/content' ]);
    });
});
```

I guess the problem becomes pretty obvious here. *r.js* (the optimizer) creates that file by only linking `es5shim.js` and `tools.js` into it. Is there any good way / workaround to tell that optimizer, that it also should link the `window.js`, `header.js` and `content.js` files in this example ?

Of course the `domReady` plugin in this instance will get loaded and it will eventually execute the callback, but the structure itself here it seems, prevents the optimizer from doing its job.

**Question are**:

- If I just would list all modules in the "Top require call", would *r.js* also include+link all top `require` and `define` calls from nested and nested-nested modules into the *main-app* file ?
- They are mentioning the *include* option for *r.js* in the Docs. Does it make sense here and if so, how to properly invoke it ?

Of course you don't want to lose the option to lazy-load modules later-on, but for this kind of dependency (waiting for DOMContentLoaded), I hope there is a way to workaround that.

Comment: I don't understand: why are you nesting requires in the first place?  Why not just make GUI/window depend on es5shim, and make es5shim depend on domready! ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

By default RequireJS doesn't scan nested require calls because it assumes those are meant to load dependencies at runtime.  You override this by setting

```
findNestedDependencies: true
```

in your optimization config.  Hope that helps.

Comment: This is really useful to know, and not particularly easy to find in the RequireJS docs

Comment: Note if you declare your config using the require = {...} form this will not work, as the require variable will shadow the nested require calls. Using a different config format fixes it, e.g. requirejs.config({...})